# Is it possible to add a set of elements in one cell in mysql?

Tags: mysql, cell, records

I have a sensor sends x,y and z values, I want to save this data in one row/cell in MySQL database. Because the sensor sends thousands of data (x,y,z) in a minute and I know if I insert each x,y and z data in a new row then it will take time to fetch all these data and that's time-consuming. I know this is possible in Neo4j but I am not sure if it is possible in MySQL. If it is, Can anybody please help me by showing an example?

The next image shows how I want the data to be inserted.
[[image: Example of the database that I am trying to use]]

Comment: from the looks of it, x, y and z should be different columns on the same row. it would perhaps cause inconvenience of having to remove x and z from the value returned from the database if for some function only y was required in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySQL 5.7, you can have [JSON fields](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html):

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('[{"x":20,"y":40,"z":50},{"x":30,"y":50,"z":60}]');
```

Then, to get for example all X coordinates per row:

```
SELECT data->"$[*].x" FROM t1;
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4JsS8ZwAeXrGgeiFbXqATM/1)

However, I think having a separate field for each coordinate would be OK too. Even if you have all the coordinates in one field, you're going to need to handle them in your app. Most of the times you can't beat the MySQL in optimized retrieving of data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer mate. is it possible that the same key can have different values in the same cell? as my image shows. @ishegg

Comment: Absolutely. It's a JSON field, you can put anything you can encode into JSON. I've edited the answer to show more recorded data.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of the database creation because I have looked at your link, but still couldn't find the way of the database creation.

Comment: [Example of structure here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4JsS8ZwAeXrGgeiFbXqATM/0)

Comment: Really appreciate your help mate, Just one more question. If you could show me how can I get the Xs values as an example.

Comment: It's no problem. With `SELECT data->"$[*].x" FROM t1;` you can get all the X coordinates per row.

Comment: Great, Thank you very much boss